# How to query WordReference from external app

Tags: javascript, api, rest

What's the best approach in order to query WordReference.com (using search function, get definition/translation etc ...) ?
It seems that a dedicated API have existed but I don't know if it's still alive.
Any informations about either ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fetch` to get the URL corresponding the word you're searching.

```
const response = await fetch('https://www.wordreference.com/definition/get')
const text = await response.text()
console.log(text)
```

But that might be against the website terms of use, you'd have to check that first. Also, the response will be the source code of the page, so you'll have to deal with that by parsing it to suit what you're trying to do.

You might also have problems with "Same-Origin Policy".

MDN Docs on Fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SleepWaterTea you're welcome, but the comments should not be used for thanking or anything like that, only to discuss the question or solutions. If the answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted, at least until a better answer is given. You can read about comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: It seems scraping is not allowed without written permission from WordReference.